# Android: Como obter o username no Google Play Games

Tags: android, jogos, google-play

Estou a desenvolver um jogo e após o jogador fazer o `sign in` é reencaminhado para outra Actividade dentro do jogo. O meu problema é que não sei como obter o `username` dele nessa actividade em que ele entra após o `Sign In`. Tenho que voltar a fazer `Sign In` na segunda actividade?

Tentei fazer isto:

```
GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).toString();
```

mas o que me devolveu foi: `com.google.candroid.gms.auth.api.signin@` e eu quero o `username` dele.

Alguém sabe como obter o `username`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, blza?

Use o `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount` método para solicitar informações sobre o perfil do usuário atualmente conectado.

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
if (acct != null) {
  String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
  String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
  String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
  String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
  String personId = acct.getId();
  Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
}
```

para saber mais, acesse a documentação: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people

Comment: Obrigada! Funcionou!